# Where to i handle the "Enter" key event for a particular mfc edit control?

Tags: c++, mfc

i have multiple edit control boxes in my gui, i want it to work such a way that the user can edit the value in a particular edit control box and when he/she hits the "Enter" i want to grab the value and do something. So my question is where can i do this "Enter" event which allows me to grab value of the edit control box which he/she hits the "Enter" key at(which is also where the cursor is at). Thanks!

Comment: There is an msdn article dedicated to your question.
Please check <http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102589>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MFC but standard edit controls need to be super/subclassed so you can handle enter, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If your edit control is on CDialog then you need to override OnOk and process the values there. If you really want to validate it whenever you change the values then you need to handle it in ON_EN_KILLFOCUS.